# Thrift and other Rpc frameworks vs ms rpc

Tags: rpc, thrift, gsoap

What is difference between rpc frameworks like thrift or gSoap and build-in MS RPC if we talk about security configurations. MSDN describes on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379441(v=vs.85).aspx some aspects, so I can presume that there is support from Microsoft in rpc. Does this mean that if i would like to use different frameworks than MS, I need to take care of security by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question. I'm not quite sure what you really expect, but I'll try to do my best to answer your question.

First, of course you have to take care of the security of whatever you are writing, be it server or client code. Security with regard to RPC services is a wide field, and any sophisticated security feature made available to you by a framework is still just a tool, and still only one part of the overall security concept of your service. To put it in another way: Using SSL will not protect your server from SQL-Injection.

Next, Thift , SOAP and MS-RPC each have different design goals. Thrift is designed with performance and portability in mind. Thrift is more focused on the basic RPC to provide efficiency and portability to any application, for any purpose, in the simplest possible way that works. Of course this approach implies, that there are not much higher-level features, because this is considered being out of the scope of Thrift and left to the user. However, for some of the languages TLS (SSL) transports are available.

In contrast, SOAP is a much richer protocol, based on XML as an machine-readable, standardized and *extendable* format which can be extended to support higher level features like WS-Security, WS-ReliableMessaging and so on. The downside is, that I have seen many frameworks and development tools which - despite the fact that SOAP has been standardized years ago - are still not able to deal with SOAP in the simpest fashion correctly, let alone supporting WS-Security. Yet, even in spite of this and even in spite of the fact, that SOAP messages tend to produce a lot of traffic and give bad performance, SOAP is still widely used in the industry.

MS-RPC as one of the foundations of DCOM is bound very much to the Windows environment and to Windows development tools. If you can live with that limitation and want to use DCOM, then DCOM offers a very high-level abstraction with good and proven support in today's IDEs.